# pandas 'chunked' save to_csv of pivoted table on very large dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My original file to pivot is very large for memory:

```
tbl = pd.read_csv('tbl_sale_items.csv',sep=';',dtype={'saleid': np.str, 'upc': np.str})
tbl.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 18570726 entries, 0 to 18570725
Data columns (total 2 columns):
saleid    object
upc       object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 283.4+ MB
```

The unique UPCs are around 40000 and the SALEID row will be around a million+.

The file looks like:

```
    saleid                              upc
0   155_02127453_20090616_135212_0021   02317639000000
1   155_02127453_20090616_135212_0021   00000000000888
2   155_01605733_20090616_135221_0016   00264850000000
3   155_01072401_20090616_135224_0010   02316877000000
4   155_01072401_20090616_135224_0010   05051969277205
```

It represents one customer (saleid) and the items he/she got (upc of the item)

I correctly pivot the table using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353758/pandas-pivot-table-of-sales).

```
                                   02317639000000 00000000000888 00264850000000 02316877000000
155_02127453_20090616_135212_0021               1              1              0              0
155_01605733_20090616_135221_0016               0              0              1              0
155_01072401_20090616_135224_0010               0              0              0              0
```

So, columns are unique UPCs and rows are unique SALEIDs.

Its not possible to pivot such a big file in memory (even 128gb that I have)
I try to read and save it in chunks:

```
chunksize = 1000000
f = 0
for chunk in pd.read_csv('tbl_sale_items.csv',sep=';',dtype={'saleid': np.str, 'upc': np.str}, chunksize=chunksize):
    print(f)
    t = pd.crosstab(chunk.saleid, chunk.upc)
    t.head(3)
    t.to_csv('tbl_sales_index_converted_' + str(f) + '.csv.bz2',header=True,sep=';',compression='bz2')
    f = f+1
```

But! Doing so the resulting pivoted tables only have the unique UPCs in Columns that exist in the chunk, usually around 25000, not all of the Columns that should be around 40000.
I need consistent number of columns and order of columns of course.

How do I read, pivot and write to csv in chunks but also keep a unified Column structure on all resulted CSVs?

Comment: you need to append for each chunk add `mode='a'` as a param to `to_csv`

Comment: Do you *really* need upcs as columns? I'm not sure of your exact requirements but it'd make more sense to have a multiindex of saleid and upc, with a single column as count, surely? `tbl.groupby(['saleid', 'upc']).size()` would make more sense...

Comment: @EdChum im not sure what you mean?!

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I need all UPCs as columns and 0/1 for each saleID (customer order) as Im going to use the data for machine learning. So I need consistent input size and input ordering.

Comment: You're overwriting on each iteration you want to append don't you? try `t.to_csv('tbl_sales_index_converted_' + str(f) + '.csv.bz2',header=True,sep=';',compression='bz2', mode='a')`

Comment: @EdChum str(f) is increasing, Im writing multiple files. not one big file. But all output files need to have a common column structure (size and ordering).

Comment: No chance of a working solution? :S